# how to batch replace the files in a directory windows vista(from .txt.txt to .txt)

Tags: windows, dos, batch-file, system-administration

I have a couple of flat files(.txt) in a directory.all those files are in the format *.txt.txt so i want to rename it to *.txt ?Is there any simple way to rename all together?

when I tried `ren *.txt.txt *.txt` is is not working

Any experts please suggest?It is amazing I have not got any answer yet
[image]

Please be noted that I need an out of the format filename.txt.

Comment: did you tried `ren *.txt.txt *.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
ren *.txt.txt *.
```

The reason your command didn't work is because, to windows, the file `file.txt.txt` is called `file.txt` with a `.txt` extension.

Only the last extension is the real extension, the first then becomes part of the filename, hence why your command changes it to what it already is.

If you did `ren *.txt.txt *.pdf` you would get `file.txt.pdf`.

My command will just remove the last one, thereby leaving the first, which then becomes the only and real extension.